# How to prevent overlap when searching for DNA codons

Tags: python, dna-sequence, python-re

I'm pretty new to this. I'm using regular expression in python to try to find specific codons in an imputed DNA sequence. Currently the code works but won't notice overlap (i.e. if the last letter of a codon before it is A and the next two on the following are A and C, it'll find a WRC codon that doesn't truly exist). Is there a way I could modify this?

```
import re
while True:
    DNA = input("enter the DNA sequence:")
    print('WRC:')
    wrcpattern = re.compile(r'(A|T)(A|G)C')
    wrcmatches = wrcpattern.finditer(DNA)
    for match in wrcmatches:
        print(match)
    print('SYC:')
    sycpattern = re.compile(r'(C|G)(C|T)C')
    sycmatches = sycpattern.finditer(DNA)
    for match in sycmatches:
        print(match)
    print('')
```

Edit: I also tried to add this to split it into codons

```
x = 3
res=[DNA[y-x:y] for y in range(x, len(DNA)+x,x)]
DNA = res
```

But this returns an error, I think re can't use a set of split strings like that.

Comment: Maybe you should add a concrete example: input, wrong output, wanted output.
Are you aware of "[negative] lookahead assertion"—https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html ?

Comment: I've tried lookaheads but they haven't worked, I probably did it wrong though.

Comment: If I understand correctly, codons are basically triples. Is that correct?
e.g. given a sequence 123456, you actually would only consider 123 and 456 valid triples, right?

Comment: Yes, I only need results returned that are correct triplets. So if I entered ACCC... I wouldn't want a result for CCC because it's not a triplet, ACC is the triplet/codon.

Answer (score 0):

## Sets of Codons

Given an input sequence of letters, you want to interpret it as a sequence of codons and they look for a small set of specific codons.  Python sets are great at answer this type of question. For example, to check for WRC, one solution is

```
wrcset = set(['AAC', 'TAC', 'AGC', 'TGC'])
for codon in (DNA[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(DNA),3)):
  if codon in wrcset:
    print(codon)
```

## RE

If you want to use a regular expression, you can use a non-greedy repetition of 3-long character slugs to skip over non-matching codons and then match on the desired expression.  The matches that come back from the iterator will have both the skipped codons and the target ones in different capture groups (or you can make the first capture group non-capturing).  For example, the SYC match can be written as

```
for i in re.compile('(.{3})*?((C|G)(C|T)C)').finditer(DNA):
  print(i.group(2))
```